# How to fix bottom navigation bar not showing correctly

Tags: java, android, android-bottomnavigationview

I'm having the problem that when I trying to switch between the menu item. The menu item will not pointing to the correct icon.
here is the flow when i found this problem

1. starting at the (Home)fragment,then press on the second menu item (Features )

```
case R.id.nav_home:
    //home fragment transaction
    actionBar.setTitle("Home");
    HomeFragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.content, fragment1, "");
    fragmentTransaction1.commit();
    break;
```

2. second menu item (features) will go to features activity

```
case R.id.nav_features:
    //features fragment transaction
    startActivity(new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, FeaturesActivity.class));
    break;
```

3. close features activity and back to (Home) fragment

```
onBackPressed();
```

4. bottom navigation still pointing to second menu item (features).

how can I make the system point to the correct menu item ?[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should return a `boolean` for this method:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    //...
 }
```

do this :

```
 case R.id.nav_home:
      //home fragment transaction
      actionBar.setTitle("Home");
      HomeFragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = 
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.content, fragment1, "");
      fragmentTransaction1.commit();
      return true; // add this line and remove break;
```

if you don't want to select icon after click, you can return `false`.

Comment: what I'm trying to say is , when i end the activity that pop up on (features ) , the system will back to the (home) fragment while the bottom navigation button still pointing to( features) , (Home) fragment should match with the home button ?

Comment: @qing you can return `false` when *feature* is selected in `onNavigationItemSelected()` .